# Dockerコンテナに mecabの辞書、NEologdをインストールしたいのですがエラー解決が出来ません。

Tags: python, docker

local環境
macOS HighSierra

Docker環境
CentOS

です。

Dockerfileに、NEologdのインストールコマンドを記載してDockerコンテナに反映させようとしています。

手順としては、

git cloneでNEologdをダウンロード。

NEologdがあるフォルダに移動し、そこで

```
RUN ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
```

のコマンドを書いています。ローカルのPC上ではこれでうまくインストール出来たのですが、Dockerfileでコンテナにインストールしようとすると。下記エラーが出ます。

```
Step 63/64 : RUN ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
 --> Running in bc6b31c0e729
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Start..
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check the existance of libraries
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     find => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sort => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     head => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cut => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     egrep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab-config => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     make => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     curl => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sed => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cat => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     diff => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     tar => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     unxz => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     xargs => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     grep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     iconv => ok
which: no patch in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     patch is not found.
ERROR: Service 'predict-regulation-type' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

どうすれば解決出来るのかわからず苦戦しております。何かアドバイス頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから判断すると`patch`がインストールされていないためと思われます。

Debian系だと以下でインストールできます。

```
sudo apt install patch
```

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。patchをインストールし、上記のエラーは解決したのですが　今度はファイルがないというエラーが出てしまいます。なので、そもそもmecab-NEologdがインストールされていないのでは？と疑っています。

Comment: 別のエラーになると、それの状況やエラーメッセージがないと判断できないので、できれば新しい質問として出してもらえないでしょうか。