# Dockerコンテナに mecabの辞書、NEologdをインストール中、ファイルが存在しないと言われる。

Tags: python, docker, mecab

local環境 Macos HighSierra
Docker環境 CentOS
です。
Dockerfileに、NEologdのインストールコマンドを記載してDockerコンテナに反映させようとしています。
手順としては、
git cloneでNEologdをダウンロード。
NEologdがあるフォルダに移動し、そこで
`RUN ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a`
のコマンドを書いています。ローカルのPC上ではこれでうまくインストール出来たのですが、Dockerfileで コンテナにインストールしようとすると。下記エラーが出ます。

```
(venv) bash-4.2# ./bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Start..
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] : Check the existance of libraries
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     find => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sort => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     head => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cut => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     egrep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     mecab-config => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     make => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     curl => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     sed => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     cat => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     diff => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     tar => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     unxz => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     xargs => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     grep => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     iconv => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     patch => ok
[install-mecab-ipadic-NEologd] :     which => ok
which: no file in (/home/ec2-user/venv/bin:/root/.pyenv/shims:/root/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
```

このエラーはファイルが存在しないといういう意味なのでしょうか？
ローカルと同様にgit cloneしているのにどうしてファイルが存在しないというエラーが出るのか解決出来なくて困っています。
アドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: [python - Dockerコンテナに mecabの辞書、NEologdをインストールしたいのですがエラー解決が出来ません。 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48626/docker%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%86%e3%83%8a%e3%81%ab-mecab%e3%81%ae%e8%be%9e%e6%9b%b8-neologd%e3%82%92%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93) からの発展でしょうか。

Comment: はい。そうなります。以前出ていた no patch in ~ というエラーはなくなったのですが、その後上記エラーが出るようになりました。

Comment: file コマンド(おそらく /usr/bin/file) が PATH にない、という意味のメッセージです。`yum provides /usr/bin/file` を実行して、表示されるパッケージがインストールされているのかどうかを確認してみて下さい。

Comment: metropolisさん、お陰様で無事にインストールが完了しました。やはりご指摘の通り、fileがインストールされていなかったようです。ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 1):

ログを見るに、インストールに必要なコマンドが存在しているか調べている最中に、見つからなかったコマンドがあったように見えます。

`install-mecab-ipadic-neologd` のソースコードを読むと、件のログは[このあたり](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/blob/5318015d9532cbdf473e003776d5dc189f0f87d5/bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd#L322)で出力されており、このログは「`file` コマンドが見つからない」と言っているようです。

したがって後は [metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48686/docker%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%8A%E3%81%AB-mecab%E3%81%AE%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8-neologd%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%AD-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E5%AD%98%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B#comment50581_48686)通り、`file` コマンドが存在するか確かめてください。存在していなければインストールが必要です。